# Imitating OO with function pointers in c/c++, how to store them?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct

I am imitating object-oriented practices using a mix of c/c++. This is for a **homework assignment** and I would **not** like the answer, but perhaps a location to find it.

We are assigned to create:

1) A general struct

2) This struct is able to hold any types of data members

3) This struct is able to hold any function

---

As my teacher explained this, we will be holding data members, their names, functions and their names into four separate vectors. I have something of the sort already

```
struct GenericClass
{
    vector < void*(*)(GenericClass& gc, void* p) > funcs; //A void pointer whose parameters are a void pointer
    vector < string > funcsNames; //Name of the function (void pointer)

    vector < void* > data;
    vector < string > dataNames;
```

We need to be able to add functions into "funcs". The functions that we should be able to add must: 1) return a (void*) and 2) take in (void*) as parameters into the function. I've written a function to do this, although it is not complete

```
void addFunction(GenericClass& gc, void* (*fn)(GenericClass& gc, void* v), string name)
{
    gc.funcs.push_back(*fn); //??
    gc.funcsNames.push_back(name);
    return;
}
```

I know I must add to "gc.funcs" a function pointer who is able to have a (void*) as optional parameters (obviously I don't want this within this function..?) that returns a (void*) but as this is my first wade in the pool of function pointers, can anyone point me in the direction where I might need to look? Thank you

Comment: I am just curious why your teacher finds this a sane/important thing to learn...

Comment: @olevegard Please, that's just off topic. I'm currently working with embedding lua, which is a remarkably similar situation. That's a use case right there.

Comment: _'Imitating OO'_?? What should this mean, providing [tag:c++] vtable surrogates with plain [tag:c] function pointers placed in `struct` declarations? You can **do** object oriented programming in [tag:c] fairly well, there's nothing about _imitation of it_!!

Comment: @olevegard - It's simply an exercise to teach us of function pointers and an intro to functional programming
πάνταῥεῖ - Please see my other comment, it is just a lesson to learn function pointers and how they work.

Comment: @Zac I'm not sure I understand what your problem is. You are aware that the `fn` parameter to `addFunction` has the wrong type? Have you tried giving it the right type? :P

Comment: @MagnusHoff - Yes I realize that the parameter is likely wrong, however I don't know the correct form (but I have an idea I will try right now to fix it)
Captain Obvlious - It isn't the easiest of things for a beginner

Comment: Would the definition be: 

void addFunction(GenericClass& gc, void* fn(GenericClass& gc, void* v), string name)

Comment: @Zac That's pretty close. You need an extra `(*)` in there: `void* (*fn)(GenericClass& gc, void* v)` should do it.

Comment: @Zac Ah! The same goes for `funcs`. `std::vector<void*(*)(GenericClass& gc, void* p)> funcs;` is my best guess for what you are looking for.

Comment: @MagnusHoff - That seemed to make things work. Can you confirm my thoughts; it was the '(\*fn)' that made the parameter mean (I am a function pointer?) to the compiler? Likewise, the 'void*(*)' means it is a function? Why must we include the * within the ( )?

Comment: @MagnusHoff My post has been edited

Comment: You seem to have understood correctly. `(*)` is the stupid syntax they chose for function pointers. All the other stuff in the type declaration already means something. `void*` is the return type, and the other things are parameters. Something has to say "I am a function pointer!"

Comment: @MagnusHoff - That is what I am thinking too, good! I'm glad to know I'm learning this now. Thank you

Comment: Why has nobody mentioned `std::function` yet? I mean, if you have to do this, do it the correct way right away from the start.

Comment: +1 This a perfectly valid question about the principle of c++. Don't know why so many laugh at it.

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting this in terms of your comments:

Your have a function of the form

void* myFunction(GeneralClass& gc, void v);

and you want to write a pointer to a new function which will accept a pointer to this function as an argument.

Let's do it the hard way first. A pointer to myFunction would be of the form

```
void* (*ptrToMyFunction)(GeneralClass& gc, void v);
```

A function which takes that pointer as an argument (and returns void) would have the form

```
void addFunction( void* (*ptrToMyFunction)(GeneralClass& gc, void v) );
```

And a pointer to THAT function would have the form

```
void (*ptrToAddFunction)( void* (*ptrToMyFunction)(GeneralClass& gc, void v) );
```

... which is hard to read even for an experienced C programmer. The better solution is to use typedefs to build it up in comprehensible stages.

```
typedef void* MyFunctionType(GeneralClass& gc, void v);  
typedef MyFunctionType *PtrToMyFunctionType;
typedef void AddFunctionType(PtrToMyFunctionType);
typedef AddFunctionType *PtrToAddFunctionType;
```

Then declare the field in your structure as

```
PtrToAddFunctionType ptrToAddFunctionType;
```

and you're done. One of the huge advantages of this approach is that in most cases, some or all of the intermediate types will also turn out to be useful.

Hope I've understood you correctly this time. If not, I think I've given you enough information to let you solve the problem you're actually dealing with.

Comment: I am looking for a similar form of what you have just typed, except I need a function pointer within my struct, that points to a function that adds a void* (*)(GeneralClass& gc, void* v) function to the struct's vector

Comment: Note: I'm approaching this as a C programmer, since you said "pointer" rather than "reference" -- with the exception of the GeneralClass reference you included in your description of the problem. But the principles I've illustrated should be valid for C++ too.